# Is there a predefined way to detect if a file is a Unix socket?

Tags: files, filenames, socket

Are there predefined Emacs functions to check if a file is a Unix socket?

The best I could come up with is the following code.

```lisp
(defun socket-p (fname)
  "Return non-nil if FNAME is a Unix Socket, nil otherwise."
  (eq (string-to-char (nth 8 (file-attributes fname))) ?s))
```

Is there something else in the built-in Emacs or its core libraries?

Comment: Eshell's `eshell-pred-file-type` boils down to the same thing, FWIW.

Comment: The `(nth 8 ...)` should probably be `(file-attribute-modes ...)`  but other than that, I don't know of any other way.

Comment: files-attribute-modes being a defsubst in files.el that is always available is indeed a better way.  I did not know about it.  Thanks!

Comment: @PRouleau Those convenience accessors for `file-attributes` were added in Emacs 26, so you'll still find a lot of code using `nth`.

Comment: @Basil This is important info.  Thanks!